# Does calling new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) each time create a new instance of it?

Tags: android

Suppose you have the following method. Does it create a new instance of a `Handler` with a `Looper` object everytime the method gets called? or do it run on the same thread?

```
private void responseListener(){
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
         //TODO execeute code
        }
    });
}
```

**Based on the answers I have changed the code to this:**

```
private void responseListener() {
    if (onBitmapSaveListener != null) {
        if (handler != null && runnable != null) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }

        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 //TODO execeute code
            }
        };

        handler.post(runnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: It creates a new handler instance that posts to the main looper

Comment: @EpicPandaForce So this is a bad approach?

Comment: I mean you could probably just make one instead of a new one each time

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Allright thanks! I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Your first code creates a new `Handler` and an new `Runnable` every time you call the method. Also it runs it on the same thread every time. The `Looper` returned by `getMainLooper()` is the same within all you application.

Your second approach is a step closer but might have issues of itself.

Just setup a `Handler` within your initialization (most likely `onCreate()`) and reuse it. If the `Runnable` doesn't need variables from the scope of the method, do the same with it. Otherwise just leave this part as is.

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
private void responseListener() {
    if (onBitmapSaveListener != null) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //TODO execeute code
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can inline declaration and initialization (`private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());`). Using a handler with a main looper will always post to main thread, you can initialize it anywhere.

Comment: @tynn Thanks. I already did something similar. But not with the `final keyword`. For putting it in a context: I just wondered if it would be bad performance in the way I had it before. As you can see [here](https://github.com/Muddz/ViewToBitmap/blob/master/viewtobitmap/src/main/java/com/muddzdev/viewtobitmaplibrary/ViewToBitmap.java#L175) it is used in my little library that deals with saving views to images and the code will run everytime the user clicks on a save button in whatever app that is using my library.

Comment: @tynn Glad to hear that ineffecient has now been changed to efficient. what is not relevant ?

Comment: I mean within your implementation one instantiation of a Handler, even if not needed, might not have to much relevance for the performance.